# Is there any kind of CSS library out there?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there are any kind of CSS libraries like a Yahoo CSS Library?

Basically I am looking for something akin to JQuery but for CSS instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [CSS framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_framework)s.

Answer (score 3):

There's really not that much of a reason for a CSS library / framework (in one's opinion) as everything you'd be doing is specific to your application's style (Cascasing **Style** Sheets).

However, there is something I use alot (or the designers I work with), made by Eric Meyer called reset which is a nice tool (as it homongenizes the styles to be almost the same in all browsers), however it does force a rule upon every element on the page (which can slow stuff down sometimes).  Here's the link - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: “which can slow stuff down sometimes” — really?

Comment: yes, there's a rule on every element, so every reflow or repaint that the browser does when an element changes must consider these rules in one more spot.  also, you often munge the default values set by this stylesheet with your own variables (closer in the value inheritance chain), and this is slightly wasteful every time you change an element / transmit this over the network.  see what I mean?

Comment: http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/#low he agrees

Answer (score 1):

I guess you either mean CSS frameworks (I like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)) or something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which is supposed to make writing CSS easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is the nearest you’ll get to a CSS library, outside of the YUI stuff.

There are also standalone grid systems that make laying out your page easier, e.g. [960.gs](http://960.gs/)

Because CSS isn’t a programming language, there isn’t really much scope for abstracting out common tasks. It’s very difficult to really isolate one style from another.

What I have found useful is looking at the CSS in CSS frameworks like Blueprint, to see what they do, and how they do it. Then do a slimmed down version of that for whatever site I’m working on.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not executable code, so what do you want a library to do?

Comment: its not a library in the normal meaning.
its like some files (templates) that have best practices so i dont need to reinvite the wheel.

Comment: You need design education, not a library.

Comment: well i will give an example using jquery,
if u read tons of javascript books, u still wont be able to write javascript efficiently as you will if you use jquery library. of course you can then write your own library but this will take much more time then using what is already written and probably will be inferior to to what is written by dedicated people.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CSS framework will only truly help if your mindset and needs align with those of the framework creator.

Personally, I think that something like SASS which allows you to generate whatever style of CSS you want, with nifty features such as variables for storing colors consistently, is the best thing to use for larger projects.

Comment: yeah i agree that i can use it if my needs agree with those of the framework creator. but basicaly i want to see the code so i can learn how to create mine :)

Answer (score 0):

There are not really CSS frameworks. It's just a buzzword. A better name is "themes" or "look'n'feel".

jQuery has also several themes in its [UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) and you can even [roll your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Answer (score 0):

To not reinvent the wheel, I would recommend the [book Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598040).

Comment: i have that book already. but that was not the question.